# golang undefined: fmt.Fprntf

Tags: go

go で下記のコードを書きましたが、実行したところ `undefined: fmt.Fprntf` と出ます。
これは何が問題なのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行手順**

```
go run server.go                                                                                                                                          
# command-line-arguments
./server.go:9:2: undefined: fmt.Fprntf
```

**作成したコード**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprntf(writer, "Hello World, %s!", request.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**実行環境**

```
Go: 1.13

.zshrc:
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

単純な綴りミスで、正しくは`fmt.Fprintf`じゃないでしょうか？

エラーに出ているコードでは`fmt.Fprntf`になっており、`i`が足りません。

Comment: 誠に申し訳ございません。